# Is it permitted to eat sacred/sacral food of other nations?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, food, non-jewish-holidays

Is it permitted by our tradition to eat religious meals of the nations?
For example, Ashure (Noah's pudding) of the Muslims, Kutia of the Polish and Ukrainian Christians, painted eggs of the Russian Christians, sweets of the Vaishnavs (Krishnaism) and turkey of the Protestants.

I'm trying to avoid eating such meals, especially on their holidays. The main reason is to distinguish, and not to confuse anyone, thinking it's ok to join their celebrations even by eating similar meal on the same day.

But is it really that strict in Halacha or a minhag?

Comment: It was a well known custom of Egyptian Jews to rat these foods when invited to the celebrations if the food was kasher. However, this might not have been allowed by the books

Comment: Turkey on thanksgiving is usually considered diferent as it is not a "sacred" celebration of the avodas zara.

Comment: Would this be assur under U'vchukoseihem lo seiliechu?

Answer (score 1):

The Sefer HaChinuch and Maimonides frequently say that the reason behind a Torah prohibition is that such foods/practices/clothing are used in idolatry i.e. the religious rites of other nations. Therefore, it would seem to be forbidden to eat any such food or do any such practice outright, even one not mentioned in classical sources.

Comment: This answer confuses _ta'ama dikra_; reasons for halacha and mitzvot, and the mitzvot themselves, in my humble opinion.